# How can I link the value of a cell to a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having some trouble with this exercise, I have a data validation list in a cell (A,B & C) and also 3 sheets with those names. What I'm trying to do is to link the value of that cell so I can be re-directed to the Sheet that has it's name in the cell

Comment: Mind posting some more details if possible? Here's some helpful tips: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is impossible - data validation items cannot be linked to a browser action.

One possible workaround would be to create a range with each cell containing a hyperlink formula with the name and url of the sheets you want to link. Then you would create a data validation based on this range and users could click on the link after selecting from the dropdown.